# Unificar coluna a conjunto de dados e colocar este conteúdo abaixo de uma tabela

Tags: r

Tenho tabela tenho uma coluna que é *um conjunto de dados* preciso separar estes dados e unificá-los as "colunas padrões".

Já consegui separar o conteúdo da coluna ficando desta forma:

```
nrow  temp area   sep1 sep2  sep3   sep4  sep5  sep6    
 1      x     x    x     x     x     x    NA    NA  
 2      x     x    x     x     x     x    x     NA  
 3      x     x    x     x     NA    NA   NA    NA  
100000  x     x    x     x     x     x    x     x
```

Porém preciso fazer isto ainda:

```
nrow  temp area   sep1 
 1      x     x    x     
 2      x     x    x     
 3      x     x    x     
100000  x     x    x     
nrow  temp area   sep2 
 1      x     x    x     
 2      x     x    x     
 3      x     x    x     
100000  x     x    x     
nrow  temp area   sep3 
 1      x     x    x     
 2      x     x    x     
 3      x     x    NA
100000  x     x    x     
nrow  temp area   sep4 
 1      x     x    x     
 2      x     x    x     
 3      x     x    NA
100000  x     x    x    
nrow  temp area   sep5 
 1      x     x    NA
 2      x     x    x     
 3      x     x    NA
100000  x     x    x     
nrow  temp area   sep6 
 1      x     x    NA
 2      x     x    NA    
 3      x     x    NA    
100000  x     x    x
```

Para isto tentei separar a colunas e juntar com um laço de repetição, mas não consigo terminar o código, abaixo o que tentei fazer:

```
file_split = data.frame(colsplit(file_unic$UNIR, pattern=";",  names=paste0("sep", 1:34)))### separar coluna 

     for(i in 1:ncol(file_split)){
     uniao = cbind(file,sep) # juntar uma coluna previamente separada ao conjunto de dados
     }
```

Contudo, ainda precisaria colocar um bloco abaixo do outro.Como posso terminar isto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é exatamente o que você quer, mas acho que pode te ajudar.

Vou assumir o seguinte `data.frame`. Publicar o resultado esperado ajuda, mas ajudaria mais se você fornecesse um exemplo mais completo na questão.

```
df <- data.frame(temp = c(10.1, 10.2, 10.3), 
                 area = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                 sep1 = c(1, 2, 3),
                 sep2 = c(10, 20, 30),
                 sep3 = c(100, 200, 300))

df;
  temp area sep1 sep2 sep3
1 10.1    A    1   10  100
2 10.2    B    2   20  200
3 10.3    C    3   30  300
```

Agora a transformação que acho que pode te ajudar.

```
library(tidyr);
gather(df, sep, value, -temp, -area)

  temp area  sep value
1 10.1    A sep1     1
2 10.2    B sep1     2
3 10.3    C sep1     3
4 10.1    A sep2    10
5 10.2    B sep2    20
6 10.3    C sep2    30
7 10.1    A sep3   100
8 10.2    B sep3   200
9 10.3    C sep3   300
```

Comment: eu tentei fazer isto para os meus dados, mas deu o seguinte erro 
Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped @MarcosBanik

Comment: Não se é permitido neste fórum, mas eu posso disponibilizar meu código completo e o arquivo no dropbox?

Comment: seria melhor mudar o meu exemplo. Por exemplo, estou desconfiado que o conteúdo de sep1, sep2, sep3 são apenas letras como 'a, b, c' ou NA. se for isso tente usar df[3:8] <- lapply(df[3:8], factor, levels=letters). 3:8 é o intervalo com o número das colunas contendo os seps. Verifique essa resposta do SOEN https://stackoverflow.com/a/25689246, acho que ela pode te ajudar.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema com o seu comentário, fiz uma modificação.
Fiz leitura o arquivo com o fread e usei o colClasses = "character". Deixando tudo como a mesma classe o seu modelo funcionou. Muito obrigada =)